# Restrict scheduled report emails on 0 records

Tags: email-alert, custom-reports, schedule

There is any way to restrict scheduled report send email when report has 0 records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe a report to send email notification in a periodic basis if record count>0

[image: Report Subscription]

Refer [Schedule and Subscribe to Reports](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_subscribe_overview.htm&type=5)